# Plot peak markers using geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

**DATA**

```
dput(test)
structure(c(1, 0.998, 1.007, 0.998, 0.982, 0.988, 0.987, 0.982, 
0.983, 0.986, 0.987, 0.993, 0.982, 0.984, 0.987, 0.99, 0.987, 
0.983, 0.975, 0.986, 0.979, 0.994, 0.976, 0.973, 0.974, 0.969, 
0.974, 0.978, 0.975, 0.965, 0.971, 0.976, 0.976, 0.971, 0.979, 
0.98, 0.969, 0.978, 0.953, 0.974, 0.962, 0.965, 0.967, 0.965, 
0.966, 0.962, 0.965, 0.966, 0.967, 0.972, 0.971, 0.972, 0.961, 
0.964, 0.96, 0.965, 0.979, 0.973, 0.968, 0.978, 0.965, 1.023, 
1.423, 1.744, 1.82, 1.847, 1.838, 1.808, 1.735, 1.682, 1.619, 
1.572, 1.495, 1.448, 1.425, 1.39, 1.354, 1.323, 1.296, 1.269, 
1.233, 1.208, 1.194, 1.172, 1.164, 1.141, 1.137, 1.112, 1.105, 
1.101, 1.085, 1.084, 1.07, 1.081, 1.066, 1.05, 1.055, 1.045, 
1.033, 1.052, 1.046, 1.031, 1.019, 1.034, 1.018, 1.018, 1.027, 
1.01, 1.01, 1.015, 1.013, 1.017, 0.999, 1.005, 1.011, 1.008, 
0.994, 0.994, 0.995, 0.994, 0.997, 0.991, 0.998, 0.994, 0.99, 
0.989, 0.983, 0.988, 0.992, 0.987, 0.993, 0.975, 0.996, 0.99, 
0.993, 0.987, 0.973, 0.987, 0.99, 0.98, 0.987, 0.978, 0.982, 
0.976, 0.987, 0.983, 0.985, 0.989, 0.99, 1.113, 1.524, 1.76, 
1.82, 1.838, 1.799, 1.75, 1.693, 1.63, 1.569, 1.508, 1.474, 1.421, 
1.382, 1.34, 1.32, 1.293, 1.262, 1.231, 1.207, 1.186, 1.181, 
1.146, 1.144, 1.127, 1.117, 1.091, 1.094, 1.087, 1.081, 1.072, 
1.067, 1.064, 1.053, 1.048, 1.044, 1.028, 1.035, 1.025, 1.023, 
1.028, 1.021, 1.021, 1.025, 1.019, 1.009, 1.005, 1.018, 1.011, 
1.006, 1.011, 1.012, 1.004, 1.017, 0.993, 1.014, 0.994, 0.996, 
0.996, 1.001, 0.998, 0.988, 0.991, 0.996, 0.974, 0.982, 0.979, 
0.986, 0.988, 0.992, 0.986, 0.98, 0.98, 0.977, 0.982, 0.985, 
0.979, 0.975, 0.98, 0.988, 0.982, 0.972, 0.972, 0.982, 0.982, 
0.96, 0.981, 0.983, 0.985, 1.122, 1.541, 1.758, 1.831, 1.838, 
1.813, 1.716, 1.659, 1.617, 1.55, 1.512, 1.457, 1.415, 1.383, 
1.35, 1.317, 1.278, 1.259, 1.238, 1.201, 1.179, 1.155, 1.159, 
1.139, 1.128, 1.115, 1.097, 1.096, 1.079, 1.085, 1.071, 1.072, 
1.052, 1.066, 1.053, 1.051, 1.044, 1.037, 1.044, 1.033, 1.031, 
1.031, 1.023, 1.02, 1.014, 1.011, 1.018, 1.007, 1.004, 1.008, 
1.01, 1.012, 0.995, 1.004, 0.987, 1.003, 0.993, 0.99, 0.992, 
0.986, 0.992, 0.991, 0.99, 0.991, 0.984, 0.988, 0.986, 0.995, 
0.994, 1.003, 0.999, 0.998, 1.115, 1.486, 1.717, 1.805, 1.787, 
1.759, 1.699, 1.634, 1.574, 1.539, 1.478, 1.43, 1.381, 1.361, 
1.313, 1.293, 1.258, 1.224, 1.214, 1.169, 1.173, 1.158, 1.136, 
1.123, 1.109, 1.113, 1.101, 1.095, 1.078, 1.075, 1.069, 1.064, 
1.045, 1.045, 1.042, 1.046, 1.031, 1.037, 1.022, 1.021, 1.008, 
1.01, 1.018, 1.019, 1.018, 1.014, 1.012, 1.01, 1.006, 1.018, 
1.007, 1.004, 0.995, 1.004, 1, 0.993, 1.014, 1.003, 0.998, 1, 
0.994, 0.984, 0.983, 0.998, 0.994, 1, 0.987, 0.985, 0.98, 1, 
1.009, 1.097, 1.45, 1.7, 1.789, 1.806, 1.765, 1.713, 1.631, 1.583, 
1.523, 1.489, 1.428, 1.392, 1.343, 1.315, 1.29, 1.25, 1.221, 
1.206, 1.18, 1.166, 1.149, 1.14, 1.118, 1.113, 1.103, 1.084, 
1.088, 1.069, 1.072, 1.058, 1.071, 1.049, 1.047, 1.042, 1.045, 
1.032, 1.034, 1.024, 1.023, 1.032, 1.024, 1.015, 1.016, 1.027, 
1.009, 1.01, 1.004, 1.013, 1.015, 1.009, 1.009, 0.998, 1, 0.988, 
1.003, 0.994, 0.988, 0.986, 0.989, 1.002, 0.993, 0.995, 0.983, 
0.994, 0.989, 0.988, 0.99, 0.988, 0.983, 0.991, 0.987, 0.984, 
0.989, 0.987, 0.981, 0.981, 0.977, 0.987, 0.98, 0.972, 0.981, 
0.976, 0.977, 0.988, 0.979, 0.971, 0.976, 0.964, 0.977, 0.975, 
0.971, 0.965, 0.964, 0.975, 0.99, 1.2, 1.617, 1.803, 1.852, 1.849, 
1.799, 1.754, 1.67, 1.607, 1.567, 1.503, 1.447, 1.413, 1.362, 
1.347, 1.323, 1.279, 1.253, 1.222, 1.203, 1.175, 1.172, 1.149, 
1.138, 1.132, 1.113, 1.096, 1.089, 1.072, 1.081, 1.077, 1.071, 
1.056, 1.062, 1.044, 1.04, 1.038, 1.046, 1.024, 1.036, 1.024, 
1.028, 1.023, 1.017, 1.005, 1.011, 1.019, 1.007, 1.011, 1.01, 
0.992, 1.003, 1.004, 1.006, 0.996, 1.002, 1.004, 1.002, 1.007, 
0.999, 0.989, 1.002, 1.005, 0.995, 0.982, 0.983, 0.982, 0.992, 
0.984, 0.995, 1.008, 1.205, 1.569, 1.753, 1.817, 1.814, 1.758, 
1.702, 1.639, 1.576, 1.513, 1.455, 1.415, 1.387, 1.343, 1.31, 
1.266, 1.249, 1.223, 1.202, 1.175, 1.155, 1.139, 1.133, 1.106, 
1.102, 1.096, 1.086, 1.078, 1.071, 1.071, 1.05, 1.049, 1.044, 
1.038, 1.045, 1.039, 1.036, 1.034, 1.032, 1.029, 1.024, 1.016, 
1.024, 1.017, 1.013, 1.011, 1.022, 1.007, 1.013, 1.001, 1.001, 
1.001, 1.002, 1, 0.996, 1.004, 0.993, 0.986, 0.982, 0.997, 0.993, 
0.993, 0.992, 0.995, 0.986, 0.993, 0.995, 0.977, 0.986, 0.989, 
0.996, 0.989, 0.991, 0.983, 0.988, 0.979, 0.985, 0.98, 0.988, 
0.99, 0.997, 0.988, 0.99, 0.98, 0.97, 0.983, 0.984, 0.988, 0.989, 
0.984, 0.975, 0.979, 0.976, 0.98, 0.988, 0.982, 0.988, 0.98, 
0.982, 0.987, 0.983, 0.996, 0.986, 0.987, 0.987, 0.98, 0.991, 
0.981, 0.983, 0.987, 0.978, 0.99, 0.979, 0.981, 0.985, 0.978, 
0.984, 0.984, 0.982, 0.977, 0.98, 0.977, 0.993, 0.995, 0.993, 
1.073, 1.453, 1.791, 1.932, 1.971, 1.967, 1.93, 1.887, 1.801, 
1.745, 1.682, 1.626, 1.57, 1.516, 1.483, 1.438, 1.41, 1.387, 
1.35, 1.32, 1.289, 1.265, 1.249, 1.226, 1.21, 1.193, 1.17, 1.166, 
1.142, 1.13, 1.127, 1.125, 1.104, 1.1, 1.075, 1.095, 1.094, 1.078, 
1.08, 1.066, 1.066, 1.061, 1.062, 1.051, 1.052, 1.04, 1.038, 
1.04, 1.039, 1.033, 1.041, 1.023, 1.033, 1.032, 1.028, 1.028, 
1.023, 1.016, 1.025, 1.025, 1.017, 1.025, 1.024, 1.018, 1.012, 
1.01, 1.022, 1.003, 0.998, 1.01, 1.004, 1.013, 1.006, 0.996, 
1.001, 0.998, 0.998, 0.999, 0.999, 0.994, 0.996, 1.002, 0.997, 
0.996, 1.007, 1.004, 0.996, 0.995, 0.996, 0.984, 0.987, 0.992, 
1, 0.996, 0.998, 0.99, 0.996, 1.003, 1, 0.996, 0.988, 0.991, 
1.001, 0.995, 0.993, 1.004, 0.993, 0.984, 0.99, 1.07, 1.456, 
1.766, 1.901, 1.943, 1.92, 1.889, 1.838, 1.77, 1.701, 1.614, 
1.578, 1.534, 1.468, 1.438, 1.406, 1.374, 1.329, 1.315, 1.28, 
1.25, 1.231, 1.214, 1.199, 1.182, 1.158, 1.145, 1.138, 1.125, 
1.122, 1.119, 1.1, 1.09, 1.078, 1.077, 1.073, 1.059, 1.07, 1.066, 
1.064, 1.052, 1.046, 1.05, 1.048, 1.052, 1.042, 1.049, 1.049, 
1.027, 1.033, 1.024, 1.024, 1.028, 1.025, 1.026, 1.011, 1.022, 
1.012, 1.018, 1.018, 1.006, 1.023, 1.004, 1.009, 1.005, 1.009, 
1.004, 1.005, 1.004, 1.01, 1.016, 1.01, 1.003, 1.002, 0.999, 
0.997, 1.002, 0.996, 1.003, 1.005, 1, 1.004, 0.99, 0.992, 1.001, 
0.994, 0.988, 0.99, 0.994, 0.988, 0.996, 0.992, 0.992, 1.095, 
1.448, 1.754, 1.881, 1.936, 1.927, 1.872, 1.817, 1.741, 1.687, 
1.627, 1.562, 1.506, 1.464, 1.428, 1.396, 1.36, 1.322, 1.306, 
1.275, 1.245, 1.217, 1.21, 1.197, 1.169, 1.164, 1.145, 1.139, 
1.128, 1.119, 1.113, 1.115, 1.081, 1.093, 1.089, 1.074, 1.08, 
1.057, 1.071, 1.062, 1.059, 1.047, 1.033, 1.05, 1.041, 1.043, 
1.035, 1.038, 1.033, 1.027, 1.025, 1.027, 1.029, 1.026, 1.033, 
1.02, 1.026, 1.011, 1.013, 1.02, 1.004, 1.015, 1.014, 1.002, 
1.018, 1.008, 1.011, 1.002, 1.007, 1.004, 1.002, 1.001, 0.998, 
1.005, 1.003, 0.999, 0.991, 0.998, 0.993, 0.993, 1.005, 1.005, 
0.998, 1.002, 0.99, 1.004, 0.992, 0.998, 0.995, 0.995, 0.992, 
0.991, 1.007, 0.991, 0.991, 0.987, 1.001, 0.995, 0.984, 0.985, 
0.992, 0.985, 0.982, 0.984, 1.006, 0.996, 0.986, 0.996, 0.993, 
1.011, 0.997, 1.093, 1.48, 1.793, 1.904, 1.942, 1.94, 1.911, 
1.827, 1.764, 1.7, 1.646, 1.586, 1.531, 1.489, 1.443, 1.404, 
1.367, 1.348, 1.309, 1.287, 1.269, 1.239, 1.212, 1.204, 1.188, 
1.154, 1.154, 1.137, 1.124, 1.125, 1.116, 1.104, 1.108, 1.094, 
1.086, 1.076, 1.08, 1.066, 1.064, 1.056, 1.056, 1.059, 1.046, 
1.053, 1.035, 1.047, 1.04, 1.032, 1.031, 1.037, 1.027, 1.027, 
1.031, 1.03, 1.014, 1.014, 1.028, 1.022, 1.014, 1.007, 1.001, 
1.016, 1.012, 1.012, 1.003, 1.003, 1.011, 1.012, 1.014, 1.01, 
1.013, 1.012, 0.995, 1.008, 1.009, 1.001, 0.996, 1.012, 1.006, 
1, 1.013, 1.03, 1.27, 1.616, 1.813, 1.877, 1.898, 1.876, 1.829, 
1.755, 1.686, 1.618, 1.554, 1.524, 1.469, 1.423, 1.389, 1.355, 
1.314, 1.29, 1.253, 1.24, 1.226, 1.201, 1.177, 1.161, 1.147, 
1.148, 1.131, 1.114, 1.116, 1.088, 1.104, 1.097, 1.082, 1.074, 
1.076, 1.066, 1.063, 1.064, 1.053, 1.058, 1.058, 1.049, 1.032, 
1.043, 1.047, 1.054, 1.029, 1.043, 1.039, 1.021, 1.034, 1.026, 
1.029, 1.023, 1.024, 1.028, 1.017, 1.015, 1.016, 1.026, 1.003, 
1.006, 1.007, 0.998, 1.01, 1.001, 1.017, 1.001, 1.006, 1.013, 
1.004, 1, 1.009, 0.988, 1, 0.992, 0.999, 1.009, 0.995, 1.006, 
1.002, 0.99, 0.995, 0.996, 1.08, 1.426, 1.727, 1.878, 1.911, 
1.898, 1.87, 1.797, 1.72, 1.664, 1.608, 1.54, 1.496, 1.454, 1.406, 
1.387, 1.345, 1.306, 1.277, 1.248, 1.235, 1.217, 1.195, 1.171, 
1.157, 1.168, 1.131, 1.129, 1.115, 1.112, 1.104, 1.099, 1.094, 
1.082, 1.076, 1.076, 1.071, 1.051, 1.063, 1.066, 1.049, 1.059, 
1.043, 1.042, 1.033, 1.041, 1.04, 1.032, 1.037, 1.024, 1, 0.986, 
0.955, 0.933, 0.917, 0.893, 0.879, 0.855, 0.844, 0.824, 0.813, 
0.805, 0.795, 0.777, 0.771, 0.759, 0.765, 0.756, 0.759, 0.751, 
0.738, 0.733, 0.728, 0.73, 0.731, 0.722, 0.716, 0.713, 0.714, 
0.715, 0.717, 0.707, 0.713, 0.702, 0.705, 0.702, 0.701, 0.704, 
0.697, 0.693, 0.698, 0.696, 0.701, 0.69, 0.691, 0.696, 0.689, 
0.689, 0.691, 0.69, 0.693, 0.687, 0.688, 0.692, 0.68, 0.696, 
0.685, 0.687, 0.689, 0.69, 0.69, 0.686, 0.687, 0.687, 0.678, 
0.688, 0.677, 0.676, 0.686, 0.691, 0.682, 0.687, 0.678, 0.673, 
0.679, 0.689, 0.68, 0.684, 0.676, 0.684, 0.687, 0.686, 0.68, 
0.674, 0.675, 0.681, 0.675, 0.674, 0.679, 0.679, 0.686, 0.67, 
0.676, 0.682, 0.673, 0.683, 0.677, 0.681, 0.677, 0.686, 0.678, 
0.674, 0.673, 0.68, 0.67, 0.674, 0.666, 0.683, 0.678, 0.681, 
0.679, 0.668, 0.676, 0.671, 0.67, 0.674, 0.67, 0.673, 0.668, 
0.678, 0.667, 0.68, 0.669, 0.668, 0.667, 0.678, 0.67, 0.675, 
0.677, 0.669, 0.668, 0.67, 0.673, 0.672, 0.671, 0.672, 0.669, 
0.675, 0.671, 0.671, 0.671, 0.677, 0.672, 0.674, 0.674, 0.673, 
0.671, 0.675, 0.671, 0.674, 0.676, 0.671, 0.672, 0.668, 0.667, 
0.674, 0.668, 0.669, 0.669, 0.669, 0.668, 0.677, 0.662, 0.665, 
0.666, 0.673, 0.668, 0.678, 0.674, 0.666, 0.668, 0.669, 0.678, 
0.668, 0.672, 0.668, 0.675, 0.673, 0.674, 0.668, 0.708, 0.927, 
1.198, 1.298, 1.342, 1.35, 1.327, 1.286, 1.257, 1.205, 1.161, 
1.116, 1.089, 1.048, 1.027, 1, 0.97, 0.962, 0.94, 0.913, 0.896, 
0.885, 0.868, 0.855, 0.847, 0.827, 0.818, 0.811, 0.797, 0.787, 
0.782, 0.78, 0.771, 0.763, 0.75, 0.74, 0.747, 0.74, 0.746, 0.735, 
0.733, 0.724, 0.728, 0.724, 0.724, 0.711, 0.718, 0.713, 0.71, 
0.711, 0.713, 0.704, 0.711, 0.707, 0.698, 0.695, 0.704, 0.694, 
0.696, 0.688, 0.694, 0.699, 0.689, 0.695, 0.7, 0.69, 0.689, 0.696, 
0.69, 0.693, 0.686, 0.693, 0.688, 0.696, 0.689, 0.688, 0.692, 
0.688, 0.693, 0.688, 0.686, 0.682, 0.69, 0.689, 0.685, 0.687, 
0.689, 0.802, 1.022, 1.186, 1.253, 1.286, 1.261, 1.229, 1.178, 
1.141, 1.098, 1.068, 1.025, 1.007, 0.982, 0.951, 0.924, 0.905, 
0.897, 0.881, 0.853, 0.842, 0.824, 0.82, 0.805, 0.792, 0.79, 
0.777, 0.769, 0.756, 0.753, 0.752, 0.743, 0.742, 0.739, 0.735, 
0.734, 0.733, 0.724, 0.726, 0.717, 0.716, 0.716, 0.713, 0.708, 
0.716, 0.711, 0.714, 0.708, 0.7, 0.703, 0.703, 0.708, 0.7, 0.694, 
0.697, 0.694, 0.694, 0.703, 0.698, 0.693, 0.698, 0.695, 0.694, 
0.69, 0.695, 0.693, 0.695, 0.681, 0.685, 0.685, 0.683, 0.682, 
0.683, 0.688, 0.686, 0.682, 0.687, 0.68, 0.687, 0.68, 0.678, 
0.679, 0.676, 0.672, 0.684, 0.682, 0.681, 0.688, 0.683, 0.68, 
0.679, 0.683, 0.68, 0.678, 0.684, 0.684, 0.672, 0.679, 0.684, 
0.683, 0.697, 0.853, 1.077, 1.22, 1.289, 1.302, 1.277, 1.237, 
1.197, 1.151, 1.12, 1.071, 1.039, 1.004, 0.983, 0.967, 0.938, 
0.919, 0.905, 0.885, 0.866, 0.847, 0.84, 0.816, 0.808, 0.79, 
0.793, 0.774, 0.779, 0.766, 0.764, 0.756, 0.748, 0.75, 0.743, 
0.735, 0.733, 0.73, 0.73, 0.723, 0.716, 0.727, 0.724, 0.722, 
0.716, 0.712, 0.715, 0.707, 0.706, 0.715, 0.699, 0.704, 0.698, 
0.702, 0.703, 0.693, 0.7, 0.694, 0.698, 0.692, 0.692, 0.692, 
0.693, 0.7, 0.693, 0.689, 0.688, 0.693, 0.688, 0.685, 0.692, 
0.683, 0.69, 0.682, 0.688, 0.682, 0.684, 0.682, 0.686, 0.688, 
0.685, 0.685, 0.686, 0.679, 0.685, 0.686, 0.685, 0.68, 0.685, 
0.689, 0.677, 0.687, 0.684, 0.68, 0.672, 0.688, 0.679, 0.67, 
0.676, 0.676, 0.68, 0.674, 0.676, 0.678, 0.682, 0.673, 0.674, 
0.68, 0.667, 0.673, 0.675, 0.672, 0.684, 0.674, 0.674, 0.677, 
0.675, 0.665, 0.672, 0.672, 0.673, 0.673, 0.67, 0.681, 0.67, 
0.676, 0.675, 0.68, 0.67, 0.669, 0.667, 0.665, 0.669, 0.68, 0.711, 
0.907, 1.161, 1.279, 1.321, 1.328, 1.302, 1.267, 1.204, 1.172, 
1.134, 1.096, 1.059, 1.025, 1.001, 0.97, 0.95, 0.937, 0.918, 
0.895, 0.875, 0.865, 0.855, 0.838, 0.826, 0.812, 0.804, 0.792, 
0.786, 0.775, 0.778, 0.763, 0.761, 0.76, 0.747, 0.736, 0.741, 
0.735, 0.74, 0.728, 0.725, 0.722, 0.722, 0.721, 0.716, 0.716, 
0.716, 0.705, 0.709, 0.705, 0.706, 0.709, 0.708, 0.708, 0.699, 
0.706, 0.704, 0.701, 0.697, 0.687, 0.7, 0.693, 0.694, 0.696, 
0.692, 0.699, 0.696, 0.691, 0.7, 0.714, 0.859, 1.053, 1.165, 
1.218, 1.212, 1.197, 1.149, 1.107, 1.08, 1.04, 1.004, 0.976, 
0.954, 0.927, 0.906, 0.891, 0.872, 0.843, 0.832, 0.826, 0.815, 
0.803, 0.79, 0.785, 0.778, 0.764, 0.764, 0.754, 0.745, 0.741, 
1, 1.006, 1.01, 1.005, 1, 0.997, 1.002, 1.001, 1.004, 0.992, 
1, 0.999, 0.989, 1.002, 0.996, 0.993, 1.006, 0.996, 1.002, 1.006, 
1.01, 0.993, 0.988, 0.999, 1.001, 1.006, 0.995, 1.011, 1.002, 
1.003, 1.03, 1.4, 1.805, 1.961, 1.99, 2.005, 1.954, 1.912, 1.847, 
1.767, 1.711, 1.668, 1.618, 1.566, 1.512, 1.495, 1.457, 1.435, 
1.403, 1.388, 1.373, 1.355, 1.332, 1.32, 1.3, 1.288, 1.274, 1.251, 
1.234, 1.218, 1.185, 1.177, 1.166, 1.16, 1.147, 1.135, 1.126, 
1.12, 1.108, 1.113, 1.112, 1.107, 1.082, 1.086, 1.082, 1.085, 
1.069, 1.07, 1.066, 1.066, 1.079, 1.069, 1.058, 1.067, 1.06, 
1.054, 1.053, 1.035, 1.048, 1.055, 1.044, 1.044, 1.035, 1.051, 
1.033, 1.039, 1.032, 1.037, 1.036, 1.051, 1.04, 1.025, 1.03, 
1.026, 1.024, 1.03, 1.021, 1.041, 1.03, 1.029, 1.036, 1.027, 
1.034, 1.019, 1.03, 1.032, 1.036, 1.222, 1.62, 1.83, 1.922, 1.906, 
1.859, 1.808, 1.753, 1.682, 1.634, 1.585, 1.52, 1.484, 1.469, 
1.435, 1.385, 1.374, 1.329, 1.299, 1.287, 1.262, 1.244, 1.212, 
1.198, 1.186, 1.175, 1.161, 1.15, 1.144, 1.128, 1.129, 1.117, 
1.095, 1.11, 1.1, 1.089, 1.095, 1.084, 1.092, 1.078, 1.076, 1.075, 
1.068, 1.071, 1.073, 1.047, 1.06, 1.055, 1.059, 1.053, 1.053, 
1.053, 1.048, 1.048, 1.067, 1.299, 1.578, 1.726, 1.799, 1.771, 
1.714, 1.654, 1.598, 1.549, 1.501, 1.462, 1.426, 1.381, 1.359, 
1.334, 1.301, 1.276, 1.256, 1.228, 1.208, 1.199, 1.184, 1.159, 
1.156, 1.141, 1.136, 1.122, 1.124, 1.113, 1.104, 1.104, 1.098, 
1.075, 1.078, 1.08, 1.078, 1.077, 1.075, 1.064, 1.061, 1.055, 
1.05, 1.053, 1.042, 1.049, 1.058, 1.047, 1.048, 1.045, 1.033, 
1.043, 1.05, 1.035, 1.043, 1.078, 1.296, 1.578, 1.698, 1.766, 
1.76, 1.708, 1.654, 1.574, 1.532, 1.498, 1.456, 1.419, 1.39, 
1.34, 1.308, 1.289, 1.276, 1.247, 1.208, 1.192, 1.186, 1.177, 
1.154, 1.144, 1.143, 1.137, 1.117, 1.119, 1.098, 1.098, 1.093, 
1.104, 1.087, 1.085, 1.075, 1.073, 1.077, 1.058, 1.06, 1.057, 
1.064, 1.044, 1.06, 1.052, 1.053, 1.055, 1.048, 1.044, 1.036, 
1.029, 1.037, 1.04, 1.037, 1.045, 1.031, 1.026, 1.026, 1.039, 
1.036, 1.024, 1.018, 1.03, 1.037, 1.02, 1.016, 1.032, 1.037, 
1.017, 1.034, 1.02, 1.032, 1.033, 1.01, 1.029, 1.015, 1.023, 
1.024, 1.012, 1.026, 1.017, 1.009, 1.021, 1.019, 1.018, 1.016, 
1.022, 1.025, 1.02, 1.017, 1.01, 1.007, 1.025, 1.007, 0.998, 
1.01, 1.013, 1.013, 1.015, 1.019, 1.012, 1.018, 1.015, 1.016, 
1.013, 1.013, 1.014, 1.012, 1.016, 0.996, 1.018, 1.019, 1.047, 
1.382, 1.748, 1.899, 1.952, 1.958, 1.912, 1.853, 1.778, 1.736, 
1.658, 1.601, 1.56, 1.508, 1.484, 1.435, 1.418, 1.397, 1.385, 
1.361, 1.327, 1.316, 1.279, 1.249, 1.232, 1.214, 1.202, 1.181, 
1.177, 1.154, 1.156, 1.14, 1.122, 1.125, 1.124, 1.11, 1.099, 
1.101, 1.103, 1.096, 1.083, 1.08, 1.07, 1.066, 1.067, 1.075, 
1.055, 1.065, 1.058, 1.058, 1.058, 1.05, 1.053, 1.044, 1.047, 
1.036, 1.051, 1.045, 1.045, 1.035, 1.046, 1.032, 1.036, 1.032, 
1.03, 1.029, 1.025, 1.039, 1.027, 1.027, 1.031, 1.025, 1.024, 
1.014, 1.015, 1.023, 1.027, 1.025, 1.039, 1.029, 1.025, 1.015, 
1.017, 1.023, 1.027, 1.022, 1.018, 1.013, 1.022, 1.012, 1.007, 
1.012, 1.023, 1.019, 1.03, 1.011, 1.014, 1.008, 1.01, 1.01, 1.006, 
1.004, 1.016, 1.007, 1.015, 1.007, 1.017, 1.015, 1.014, 1.008, 
1.014, 1, 1.003, 1.012, 1.008, 1.014, 1.008, 1.016, 1.019, 0.997, 
1.008, 1.015, 1.156, 1.61, 1.878, 1.966, 1.986, 1.965, 1.914, 
1.847, 1.778, 1.713, 1.663, 1.608, 1.553, 1.513, 1.476, 1.447, 
1.402, 1.378, 1.355, 1.329, 1.311, 1.3, 1.261, 1.254, 1.23, 1.216, 
1.19, 1.182, 1.175, 1.152, 1.146, 1.141, 1.135, 1.125, 1.127, 
1.103, 1.114, 1.096, 1.102, 1.086, 1.082, 1.085, 1.075, 1.074, 
1.064, 1.064, 1.061, 1.074, 1.062, 1.061, 1.068, 1.054, 1.053, 
1.051, 1.045, 1.049, 1.048, 1.041, 1.035, 1.041, 1.028, 1.046, 
1.034, 1.034, 1.041, 1.029, 1.037, 1.033, 1.029, 1.027, 1.027, 
1.026, 1.03, 1.023, 1.031, 1.03, 1.026, 1.018, 1.023, 1.021, 
1.014, 1.023, 1.015, 1.016, 1.019, 1.018, 1.028, 1.018, 1.022, 
1.029, 1.016, 1.02, 1.016, 1.02, 1.018, 1.016, 1.025, 1.018, 
1.017, 1.015, 1.012, 1.008, 1.007, 1.013, 1.02, 1.007, 1.024, 
1.01, 1.003, 1.011, 1.004, 1.009, 1.011, 1.011, 1.005, 1.005, 
1.011, 0.995, 1.009, 1.005, 0.998, 1.01, 1.01, 1.019, 1.01, 1.016, 
1.002, 1.012, 1.007, 1.007, 1.006, 1.003, 1.012, 1.01, 1.006, 
1.003, 1.012, 1.009, 1.008, 1.005, 0.997), .Dim = c(601L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
    "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
    "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
    "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
    "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
    "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
    "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", 
    "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", 
    "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", 
    "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", 
    "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", 
    "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", 
    "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", 
    "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", 
    "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", 
    "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", 
    "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", 
    "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", 
    "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", 
    "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", 
    "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", 
    "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", 
    "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", 
    "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", 
    "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "254", 
    "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", 
    "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", 
    "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", 
    "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", 
    "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", 
    "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", 
    "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", 
    "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", 
    "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", 
    "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", "344", 
    "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", "353", 
    "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", "362", 
    "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", "371", 
    "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", "380", 
    "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", "389", 
    "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", "398", 
    "399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", 
    "408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
    "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", "425", 
    "426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", "434", 
    "435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", "443", 
    "444", "445", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450", "451", "452", 
    "453", "454", "455", "456", "457", "458", "459", "460", "461", 
    "462", "463", "464", "465", "466", "467", "468", "469", "470", 
    "471", "472", "473", "474", "475", "476", "477", "478", "479", 
    "480", "481", "482", "483", "484", "485", "486", "487", "488", 
    "489", "490", "491", "492", "493", "494", "495", "496", "497", 
    "498", "499", "500", "501", "502", "503", "504", "505", "506", 
    "507", "508", "509", "510", "511", "512", "513", "514", "515", 
    "516", "517", "518", "519", "520", "521", "522", "523", "524", 
    "525", "526", "527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", "533", 
    "534", "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", "540", "541", "542", 
    "543", "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", "549", "550", "551", 
    "552", "553", "554", "555", "556", "557", "558", "559", "560", 
    "561", "562", "563", "564", "565", "566", "567", "568", "569", 
    "570", "571", "572", "573", "574", "575", "576", "577", "578", 
    "579", "580", "581", "582", "583", "584", "585", "586", "587", 
    "588", "589", "590", "591", "592", "593", "594", "595", "596", 
    "597", "598", "599", "600", "601"), c("C3", "C4", "C5", "C6"
    )))
```

**CODE**

```
rownames(test)=as.numeric((1:nrow(test))) ## Time Vector
library(reshape2)
test_melt = melt(test) 


plots=ggplot(test_melt, aes(x =Var1 , y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Var2, nrow = 12) +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
ggsave('testplot.png',width = 22,height = 16)
```

I'm looking to overlay point markers on every peak in the facets using geom_point(). The peak data comes from another function and the output of that function looks like this.

**PEAK DATA**

```
dput(pks_test)
structure(list(C3 = structure(c(1.847, 1.838, 1.838, 1.805, 1.806, 
1.852, 1.817, 66, 154, 243, 314, 386, 481, 552, 61, 146, 235, 
310, 379, 475, 546, 93, 176, 260, 330, 408, 506, 577), .Dim = c(7L, 
4L)), C4 = structure(c(1.971, 1.943, 1.936, 1.942, 1.898, 1.911, 
77, 186, 279, 390, 472, 556, 72, 180, 274, 385, 465, 549, 107, 
218, 305, 411, 492, 576), .Dim = c(6L, 4L)), C5 = structure(c(1.35, 
1.286, 1.302, 1.328, 1.218, 186, 272, 373, 507, 575, 180, 265, 
367, 499, 569, 216, 305, 393, 531, 597), .Dim = c(5L, 4L)), C6 = structure(c(2.005, 
1.922, 1.799, 1.766, 1.958, 1.986, 36, 121, 176, 231, 344, 465, 
29, 114, 171, 225, 336, 458, 69, 147, 199, 254, 368, 494), .Dim = c(6L, 
4L))), .Names = c("C3", "C4", "C5", "C6"))
```

**Peak Point Attempt**

Here is the code I attempted to add to deal with this data to plot the points on the peaks.

```
plots=ggplot(test_melt, aes(x =Var1 , y = value)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Var2, nrow = 12) +
  geom_point(pks_test(aes x= ))
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

for (i in 1:length(pks_test)){
  if (!is.null(pks_test[[i]]))
    tempdf = as.data.frame(pks_test[[i]])
    plots = plots + geom_point(data=tempdf,mapping=aes(x=V2,y=V1))
}
```

But I get some errors :

```
In if (pks_test[[i]] != is.null(pks_test[[i]])) tempdf = as.data.frame(pks_test[[i]]) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any ideas?

Comment: (1) I think maybe you just wanted `if (!is.null(pks_test[[i]]) ...` and (2) Don't refer to columns via `$` inside of `aes()`. Just `x = V2` and `y = V1`.

Comment: That seems to help! when I go to plot (or save to png using ggsave) I get Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (28): x, y

Comment: Fix this: `geom_point(pks_test(aes x= ))` in your sample code so that it is actually reproducible and runs, and maybe I can help more.

Answer (score -2):

Use a different dataset to plot the points like this.
I am not sure why I needed to put `p$` in front of the variables in the `geom_point` layer.

```
x <- data.frame(t <- seq(1:100)
                ,var1 <- rnorm(100)
                ,peak <- rep(c(rep(0,4),1),20)
                ) 
p <- x[x$peak==1,]
ggplot(x, aes(x = t, y = var1)) + geom_line() + geom_point(data = p, aes(x = p$t, y = p$var1))
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. The function I'm using findpeaks, outputs a list of matrices for peaks found on a column of a data.frame. Therefore I need something that can check if the next matrix in the list from findpeaks is not NULL, use the first 2 columns to plot the points on the corresponding facet.

Comment: Ok I understand. I thought you already mastered both data, and it would have been no problem to make a peak dataset from it. I saw you tried to add points via a loop, that does not work with ggplot, and that this was the main issue.